# How to solve this null check in initializer safely?

Tags: delegates, kotlin

I'm writing a test case which I need some private properties. Since those private data are generated from a private method, I decided to use reflection to retrieve them after calculation is done. Later I remembered the delegated properties and decide to write a general delegate. Here is the code I got so far:

```
fun <T> reflect(instance: Any, initOnce: Boolean = true) = ReflectBackedProperty<T>(initOnce, instance)

class ReflectBackedProperty<T>(val initOnce: Boolean, val instance: Any): ReadOnlyProperty<Any, T>  {
    var initialized = false
    lateinit var cache: T // <--- (a)
    override opertaor fun getValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>): Any? {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        if (!initialized || !initOnce) {
            cache = instance.javaClass.getDeclaredField(property.name).get(instance) as T
            initialized = true
        }
        return cache
    }
}
```

As you can see, property `cache` is initialized by `getValue` calls, and, if `initOnce` is set, subsequent calls will use that cache instead of keeping calling expensive reflection.

The very unfortunate thing is that at (a) compiler complains because T may be a nullable type and late init mechanism will be broken, but if I initialize it with `null` and it still complains because T may be a non-null type and null-safety is broken.

Currently, I made this to work by initializing it with the return value of a null-returning Java function. I inspected the bytecode generated and found kotlin compiler placed no null checks for that so it will work for now, but I'm worried that a future kotlin version will have such checks and ruin this trick. How I'm supposed to overcome this?

---

Now I'm using this, below code is released to public domain. Mention this page if you like, or do nothing.

KTHacks.java

```
public final class KTHacks {
    private KTHacks() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    /**
     * Forge a null into a platform type and take advantage of relaxed null-checks.
     * @param <T>
     * @return
     */
    public static <T> T NULL() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

ReflectBackedProperty.kt

```
import kotlin.properties.ReadOnlyProperty
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty

fun <T> reflect(instance: Any, initOnce: Boolean = true) = ReflectBackedProperty<T>(initOnce, instance)

class ReflectBackedProperty<T>(val initOnce: Boolean, val instance: Any): ReadOnlyProperty<Any, T> {
    var initialized = false
    var cache: T = KTHacks.NULL()
    override operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        if (!initialized || !initOnce) {
            cache = instance.javaClass.getDeclaredField(property.name).get(instance) as T
            initialized = true
        }
        return cache
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to limit `T` to only non-nullable types with an upper bound:

```
class ReflectBackedProperty<T: Any> : ReadOnlyProperty<Any, T> {}
```

Another approach is not to bother with `lateinit` at all:

```
class ReflectBackedProperty<T>(val initOnce: Boolean, val instance: Any): ReadOnlyProperty<Any, T>  {
    var initialized = false
    var cache: T? = null

    override operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        if (!initialized || !initOnce) {
            cache = instance.javaClass.getDeclaredField(property.name).get(instance) as T
            initialized = true
        }
        return cache as T
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is the best solution so far. One will need to hack or use plain java if he wants both nullable and nonnull types.

Comment: @glee8e there is no (sensible) code that can be do with Java and can't be done with Kotlin

Comment: IIRC It won't work, as kotlin compiler require the return type of getValue to match the property type, or a compile error will be thrown.

Comment: Hm, yes indeed. I've fixed the type. It was a copy-paste from your code, so I expected the types to match.